# How to reject xml records if not in specific date format

Tags: date, xslt

I have a case study where i need to reject xml record if it is not in format
 `hh:mm:ss`. Can any1 help me how we can do that using xslt's.

```
<Data>
    <rec>
       12:32:56
    </rec>
    <rec>
       20141104093903
    </rec>
<Data>
```

so it should reject the second record....

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  -- And what exactly does "reject" mean?

Answer (score 0):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Data/rec[contains(., ':')]"/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rec">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to our input XML, it produces

```
<Data>
    <rec>
        12:32:56
    </rec>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thanks Joel M. Lamsen !!

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath expression

```
rec[normalize-space(translate(., '1234567890', '##########'))='##:##:##']
```

will select only `rec` elements whose content is in `hh:mm:ss` **format**. It does not check the **value** of the time, and it will happily accept a "time" of `36:82:93`.